# No alarm sounds

Tags: notifications, nexus-7

I messed around with the new volume menu and now my alarms and countdown timers aren't making any sound. Strangely, notifications such as email are still getting through. I currently have notifications set to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you have accidentally muted the alarm sounds. In the Volume Settings there is a slider for alarm volumes.